# Storing contents of file in string using command line redirection (wiith <) on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, vector, io

If i run my main.cpp in this way :

```
./main.cpp < file.txt
```

When i store this input in a vector of strings, each word of the same line is stored in  new line. How can i efficiently and elegantly store each whole line in one element of vector string? 
 For example 
I want it to be:

```
Myvector[0]= "this is just a sentence"
```

Not like:

```
Myvector[0] ="this"
Myvector[1]="is"
Myvector[3]="just" etc
```

Comment: You should really add your code y'know.

Comment: It's irrelevant where the input comes from.

Comment: It sounds like you're using `cin >> Myvector[i];`. `>>` just reads a single word. If you want to read a whole line, use `getline()`.

Comment: If you want to read a line, read a line.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Linux, or with `<`.

Comment: [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: If you'd show us the reading code, we could help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::getline`.

```
std::string text_line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, text_line))
{
  my_vector.push_back(text_line);
}
```

The `std::getline` function reads until a newline is encountered, storing the data into a string.

The `std::cin` is used because you are piping data from a file.

Comment: What if there are empty lines in the center and i just want to ignore them? Thanks i was not using while loop before thats why each word were stored in new line.

Comment: Then put an `if` statement before pushing into the vector.  See `std::string::empty()`.